# google auto complete retains the old values

Tags: autocomplete, google-api

I have implemented the google API for finding the cities of a particular Country selected.The Code is something like,

```
function initialize(ctryId) {
    var ctyId = [];
    ctyId.push(ctryId);
    console.log(ctyId[0]);
    var options = {
        types: ['(cities)']
    };
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input , options);
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': ctyId});

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        selected = true
    });
```

I am setting the country Id i.e ctyId in the above code from country dropdown.
This works fine for me.
But the issue is the old value is persisted.For example,If I select country as India and try for city autocomplete,it works perfectly fine but when I select some other country say Germany,the autocomplete options for city would include Indian cities as well.Is there anyway I can restrict the autocomplete options to the selected country  only or to clear the old values.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google API creates an element for drop down with class ".pac-container". Removing that element and creating it again works fine.

```
$(".pac-container").remove();
```